# Finding non-duplicates from two Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, gs-vlookup

I'm trying to update my shop's product list but don't want to duplicate items we already have.  I've been using `Vlookup` to find duplicates but I'm trying to get that to work in reverse.

```
=ArrayFormula(VLOOKUP(Update!$A1:$A,Shopify!$N1:$N,1,False))
```

This is the current formula.  How can I write this, basically to reverse the logic?

I want to see all the "SKU's" from the sheet: Update row: A that do NOT appear in sheet: Shopify row: N.

Answer (score 0):

for such task you can use `FILTER` either with `MATCH` or `COUNTIF`

```
=FILTER(A1:A, MATCH(A1:A, B1:B, 0))

=FILTER(A1:A, COUNTIF(B1:B, A1:A))
```

and for reverse logic:

```
=FILTER(A1:A, ISNA(MATCH(A1:A, B1:B, 0)))

=FILTER(A1:A, NOT(COUNTIF(B1:B, A1:A)))
```

and maybe wrap it into `UNIQUE` if you need to

Comment: And filter will work for comparing both sheets?  Currently i'm building a 3rd sheet to get the non-duplicate SKU's.

Comment: yes, it will. all you need to do is choose the right one